# With upcoming message chat layout doesn't move above with message rather than message get shift to another direction

Tags: android, chat

**Chat_thread.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp">

    <!-- For self message -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/balloon_incoming_normal"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout

            android:padding="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello how are you?" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Belal Khan, 2016-05-29 16:02:00?"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
**Chat_other_thread.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/balloon_outgoing_normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

        <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello how are you?" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

**Demo_chat.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/back_white"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/black_mix"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            >


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Kamal Jain"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last seen 2 days ago"
                android:textColor="#b6dbe5"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_no_border"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_no_border"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_no_border"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--main title end here-->


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/footer_for_emoticons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/keyboard_height"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**GroupChatListAdapter.class**

```
package com.trackliy.trackliy.messanger;

/**
 * Created by cbr on 3/24/2017.
 */

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.trackliy.trackliy.R;
import com.trackliy.trackliy.Session;
import com.trackliy.trackliy.model.GroupMessageModel;
import com.trackliy.trackliy.model.Message;

public class GroupChatListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Spanned> comments;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Session session;

    //Tag for tracking self message
    private final int Comment_Log_In_User = 0;
    private final int Comment_Other_User = 1;


    //ArrayList of messages object containing all the messages in the thread
    private ArrayList<GroupMessageModel> groupMessagesList;

    //  public ChatListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Spanned> comments,String users) {
    //Constructor
    public GroupChatListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupMessageModel> groupMessages) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.groupMessagesList = groupMessages;
        session = new Session(context);
        this.comments = comments;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    public void addGroupMessage(GroupMessageModel m) {

        groupMessagesList.add(m);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addGroupMessageList(ArrayList<GroupMessageModel> groupMessagesList) {

        this.groupMessagesList.addAll(groupMessagesList);

        Log.d("Addmessage",groupMessagesList.toString());

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        //getting message object of current position
        GroupMessageModel message = groupMessagesList.get(position);
        // Here you have to write logic for which position have which type of row and return the same
        if (message.getUserid().equals( session.get_id())) {
            return Comment_Log_In_User;
        } else if (!message.getUserid().equals(session.get_id()) ) {
            //Returning other user
            return Comment_Other_User;

        }

        //else returning position
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        //  View v = convertView;
        if (getItemViewType(position) == Comment_Log_In_User) {

            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_thread, parent, false);//set layout for displaying items
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textViewMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
                holder.textViewTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
                // holder.reciever_UserName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chat_user_name);
                view.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            GroupMessageModel message = groupMessagesList.get(position);

            SpannableString spannedTxt = new SpannableString(message.getMessage());

            holder.textViewMessage.setText(spannedTxt);

            //holder.textViewTime.setText(message.getTime_stamp());

            String formatedDate = convertTimeStampIntoFormat(String.valueOf(message.getTime_stamp()));

            holder.textViewTime.setText(formatedDate);

        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == Comment_Other_User) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_thread_other,parent, false);//set layout for displaying items
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textViewMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
                holder.textViewTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
                // holder.reciever_UserName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chat_user_name);
                view.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            GroupMessageModel message = groupMessagesList.get(position);

            holder.textViewMessage.setText(message.getMessage());

            holder.textViewTime.setText(message.getName());

            String formatedDate = convertTimeStampIntoFormat(String.valueOf(message.getTime_stamp()));

            holder.textViewTime.setText(formatedDate);

        }

        // final Spanned item = comments.get(position);

        /*TextView fans_image = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        fans_image.setText(item);*/

        return view;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return groupMessagesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return groupMessagesList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private String convertTimeStampIntoFormat(String time_stamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String finalDate = "";
        if (time_stamp.contains(".")) {
            time_stamp = time_stamp.substring(0, time_stamp.indexOf('.'));
        }
        try {

            finalDate = sdf1.format(sdf2.parse(time_stamp));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalDate;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewMessage;
        public TextView textViewTime;
        public TextView reciever_UserName;
    }
}
```

Whenever I send or fetch a new message, the layout of the message doesn't shift with the message rather than message get shift in other direction.
i.e left to right but it should move on the same direction.

Please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: There is a lot of code here and very little of your own analysis. Please consider doing as much troubleshooting as possible to narrow down the problem area, then try to create a Minimal, Complete Viable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Charlie, i will surely make correction there.
Actually, when i  send first  message it start from right direction then on sending second message ,first message get shift to left direction rather going above in the list.